# backoffice is not loading in hybris 1808

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I have upgraded from hybris 6.7 to 1808. Backoffice is not loading . Returned 404 error page with below error in Console.

Error Log:
ERROR [localhost-startStop-2] [ContextLoader] Context initialization failed
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/02/03 07:54:51.652 |  java.lang.VerifyError: Bad return type
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/02/03 07:54:51.652 | Exception Details:
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/02/03 07:54:51.652 |   Location:
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/02/03 07:54:51.652 |     com/hybris/backoffice/BackofficeApplicationContext.getClassLoader()Lcom/hybris/cockpitng/core/persistence/packaging/CockpitClassLoader; @4: areturn
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/02/03 07:54:51.652 |   Reason:
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/02/03 07:54:51.652 |     Type 'com/hybris/cockpitng/core/persistence/packaging/WidgetClassLoader' (current frame, stack[0]) is not assignable to 'com/hybris/cockpitng/core/persistence/packaging/CockpitClassLoader' (from method signature)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/02/03 07:54:51.652 |   Current Frame:
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/02/03 07:54:51.652 |     bci: @4
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/02/03 07:54:51.652 |     flags: { }
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/02/03 07:54:51.652 |     locals: { 'com/hybris/backoffice/BackofficeApplicationContext' }
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/02/03 07:54:51.652 |     stack: { 'com/hybris/cockpitng/core/persistence/packaging/WidgetClassLoader' }
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/02/03 07:54:51.652 |   Bytecode:
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/02/03 07:54:51.652 |     0x0000000: 2ab6 0151 b0
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/02/03 07:54:51.652 |
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/02/03 07:54:51.652 |         at com.hybris.backoffice.BackofficeApplicationContextInitializer.createDefaultWebApplicationContext(BackofficeApplicationContextInitializer.java:104) ~[classes/:?]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/02/03 07:54:51.652 |         at com.hybris.backoffice.BackofficeApplicationContextInitializer.createWebApplicationContext(BackofficeApplicationContextInitializer.java:96) ~[classes/:?]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/02/03 07:54:51.652 |         at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:312) [spring-web-4.3.29.RELEASE.jar:4.3.29.RELEASE]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/02/03 07:54:51.652 |         at de.hybris.platform.spring.HybrisContextLoaderListener.doInitWebApplicationContext(HybrisContextLoaderListener.java:233) [coreserver.jar:?]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/02/03 07:54:51.652 |         at de.hybris.platform.spring.HybrisContextLoaderListener.initWebApplicationContext(HybrisContextLoaderListener.java:207) [coreserver.jar:?]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/02/03 07:54:51.652 |         at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.29.RELEASE.jar:4.3.29.RELEASE]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/02/03 07:54:51.653 |         at de.hybris.platform.spring.HybrisContextLoaderListener.contextInitializedInternal(HybrisContextLoaderListener.java:103) [coreserver.jar:?]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/02/03 07:54:51.653 |         at de.hybris.platform.spring.HybrisContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(HybrisContextLoaderListener.java:97) [coreserver.jar:?]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/02/03 07:54:51.653 |         at com.hybris.backoffice.BackofficeApplicationContextInitializer.contextInitialized(BackofficeApplicationContextInitializer.java:112) [classes/:?]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/02/03 07:54:51.653 |         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4689) [catalina.jar:8.5.56]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/02/03 07:54:51.653 |         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5155) [catalina.jar:8.5.56]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/02/03 07:54:51.653 |         at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [catalina.jar:8.5.56]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/02/03 07:54:51.653 |         at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1412) [catalina.jar:8.5.56]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/02/03 07:54:51.653 |         at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1402) [catalina.jar:8.5.56]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/02/03 07:54:51.653 |         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_151]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/02/03 07:54:51.653 |         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_151]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/02/03 07:54:51.653 |         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_151]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/02/03 07:54:51.653 |         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: did you try and reset the configuration of your backoffice?

Answer (score 1):

- Run the impex **D:\Hybris_OOB_2011\hybris\bin\modules\backoffice-framework\backoffice\resources\impex\essentialdataBackofficeMediaCatalog.impex**
- Delete the **hybris\data\backoffice** backoffice folder
- Do ant clean all, start the server and system update specially marking the backoffice
- Please check now!!

Answer (score 0):

The issue with SAP suite itself. I have tried with different patch version and it worked.